# How do I add the number 32 to index 4?

Tags: python, list

I am creating a random list.
How do I add the specific number 32 to index 4?
The code below gives me the first six elements out of the random list but do not give me the specific number 32 to the index.

```
import random as ra
def main():
    nums = [] # an empty list
    print('Here are the temperatures, sorted ascending')
    for n in range(24):
        rnd = ra.randint(10,55)
        nums.append(rnd)
        nums.sort()
    for x in nums:
        print(x, end = ' ')
    print()
print(f'The first six elements are now',nums[0:6])
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `list.insert` method: `nums.insert(4, 32)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to **insert an additional number** into the list `nums .insert( 3, 32 )`

Or add 32 to what's already there `nums[3] += 32`

Or completely replace it  `nums[3] = 32`